# Passing variable between javascript functions not working?

Tags: javascript, variables

I tried using this method to pass a variable to the next function:

```
function a(form, ctr) {
var a = form;
var b = ctr;
b(ctr);
} 

function b(ctr) {
var b = ctr;
}
```

The exact code is a lot more complicated as i'm using the POST method with ajax: function a begins upon a click and uses both the form and ctr parameters - it then goes to function b which only needs ctr - however this method of passing the variable hasn't worked. Any better solution?

```
function updateQuestion(form, ctr) { 
console.log("Called updateQuestion");
var str1 = "toggleDiv";
var str2 = ctr;
var id = str1.concat(str2);
var divVar = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(divVar);
  var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
  console.log("XMLHttpRequestObject = TRUE");

var myVar = form.create_mcq_question.value;
  console.log("MyVar = " + myVar);
    var formQuestion = document.getElementById("formQuestion");
    console.log("1");
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST","hiddent",true); 
        console.log("2");
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
        console.log("3");
    XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        console.log("4" + document.getElementById("create_mcq_question").value);

        var mcqid;
        var mcqQuestion;
        var mcqAnswerCorrect;
        var mcqAnswerWrong1;
        var mcqAnswerWrong2;
        var mcqAnswerWrong3;
        var mcqExplanation;

        var error = 0;

        if (form.create_mcq_question.value == "" || form.create_mcq_question.value == null  ) {
        error = 1;
        }
        else {
        mcqQuestion = form.create_mcq_question.value
        }
        if (form.create_mcq_answer_correct.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_correct.value == null) {
        mcqAnswerCorrect = "";
        error = 1;
        }
        else {
        mcqAnswerCorrect = form.create_mcq_answer_correct.value
        }
        if ((form.create_mcq_answer_wrong1.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_wrong1.value == null) && (form.create_mcq_answer_wrong2.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_wrong2.value == null) && (form.create_mcq_answer_wrong3.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_wrong3.value == null)) {
        error = 1;
        }

        if (form.create_mcq_answer_wrong1.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_wrong1.value == null) {
        mcqAnswerWrong1 = "";
        }
        else {
        mcqAnswerWrong1 = form.create_mcq_answer_wrong1.value
        }
                if (form.create_mcq_answer_wrong2.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_wrong2.value == null) {
        mcqAnswerWrong2 = "";
        }
        else {
        mcqAnswerWrong2 = form.create_mcq_answer_wrong2.value
        }
                if (form.create_mcq_answer_wrong3.value == "" || form.create_mcq_answer_wrong3.value == null) {
        mcqAnswerWrong3 = "";
        }
        else {
        mcqAnswerWrong3 = form.create_mcq_answer_wrong3.value
        }

                if (form.create_mcq_explanation.value == "" || form.create_mcq_explanation.value == null) {
        mcqExplanation = "";
        }
        else {
        mcqExplanation = form.create_mcq_explanation.value
        }
        if (error == 0) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send("create_mcq_question=" + mcqQuestion +
                              "&create_mcq_correct_answer=" + mcqAnswerCorrect + 
                              "&create_mcq_wrong_answer1=" + mcqAnswerWrong1 + 
                              "&create_mcq_answer_wrong2=" + mcqAnswerWrong2 + 
                              "&create_mcq_answer_wrong3=" + mcqAnswerWrong3 + 
                              "&create_mcq_explanation=" + mcqExplanation +
                              "&mcqid=" + mcqid ); 
                                console.log("5");
                                handleServerResponse(ctr);
                                }
                                else {
                                document.getElementById("divVar").innerHTML="Cannot update question - please ensure all required fields are filled!";
                                }
  }


}

function handleServerResponse(ctr) {
var str1 = "toggleDiv";
var str2 = ctr;
var id = str1.concat(str2);
var divVar = document.getElementById(id);
console.log("Handle server response called");
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 1) {
console.log("Loading");
 document.getElementById(divVar).innerHTML="<img src=\"hidden">";
}

   if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4) {
   console.log("4");
     if(XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById(divVar).innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; //Update the HTML Form element
       console.log("divVar found");
       console.log(divVar); 
     }
     else {
       document.getElementById(divVar).innerHTML="There was a problem updating your question - please try again!"; //Update the HTML Form element 
       console.log("divVar not found");
       console.log(divVar); 
     }
   }
}
```

And the button which starts the whole thing off:

```
<input type="button" value="Update My Question!" onclick="updateQuestion(this.form,<?php echo" $ctr"; ?>)">
```

Firebug showing the first function working, and calling the second one, which doesn't get the variable:

```
[02:21:42.106] Called updateQuestion
[02:21:42.106] [object HTMLDivElement]
[02:21:42.106] XMLHttpRequestObject = TRUE
[02:21:42.106] MyVar = Gram- bacteria are stained purple with gram staining, while gram+ bacteria are stained pink.
[02:21:42.106] 1
[02:21:42.107] 2
[02:21:42.107] 3
[02:21:42.107] 4Gram- bacteria are stained purple with gram staining, while gram+ bacteria are stained pink.
[02:21:42.108] Handle server response called
[02:21:42.108] Loading
[02:21:42.108] 5
[02:21:42.108] Handle server response called
[02:21:42.109] Loading
[02:21:42.649] Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ hidden
[02:21:42.649] TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @ hidden
[02:21:42.647] Handle server response called
[02:21:42.648] 4
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. How doesn't it work? Can you post *all* of your code?

Comment: I find it much more likely that there's something going on with the "asynch" part of Ajax than that your JavaScript interpreter is suddenly fundamentally broken. (Assuming you haven't simplified too much and created nonsense example code.)

Comment: I've check firebug, function a is working fine and the ajax part is okay, it's just in function b, the ctr variable is coming up as empty.
re jack: a button with onclick="a(this.form, $ctr)"

Also, I was about to post the whole code but it's really long, the 4 space indent per line thing takes me ages

Comment: Then `$ctr` is empty; I'm positive passing parameters in JavaScript works. What do you mean, "it takes you ages"? Your editor should indent automatically, and you can select the code and hit ctrl-K to indent the whole block, or indent inside your editor before pasting...

Comment: @DaveNewton The $ctr definitely has a value, i've checked the html source. 
I've updated the question and added the whole code

Comment: If you've checked the HTML source, then it *must* be passed--that's just how JavaScript works. It's essentially impossible that if the function is being called with a valid argument that the value isn't available in the function. Include the *rendered* HTML, and the console log output.

Comment: Here is the button rendered in html: <input type="button" value="Update My Question!" onclick="updateQuestion(this.form, 1)">
The $ctr is showing up as 1 which it should. I've updated the question to include the console log: it shows the first function works and calls the second one, which, when when looking for the element by id comes up as empty

Comment: ... Your code makes no sense; you create an ID, get an element by that ID, then pass that element to `getElementById`, and the naming convention of `divVar` should serve as an indicator of that. See also Lucero's edit.

Answer (score 2):

The following makes no sense really:

```
var b = ctr;
b(ctr);
```

Here the variable `b` is treated and invoked as function, and you pass a reference to itself as the parameter. Is that really our intention?

**Edit:** Now with the additional info, the problem is easy to explain. If you look at your log, you'll notice that the handleServerResponse is invoked several times. The first time "ctr" is passed as expected.

The problem is here:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
```

This sets a callback, and the callback will invoke your function without the "ctr" of course, which is why your code runs as it does. You could use an anonymous function so that a closure is used:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() { handleServerResponse(ctr); };
```

You may want to read JavaScript: The Good Parts by Crockford, I think it would help to improve your JS coding significantly.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a variable called **'b'** inside your function scope. That's why you get the error. If they are **global** functions, you can use:

```
function a(form, ctr) {
    var a = form;
    var b = ctr;
    window.b(ctr);
} 

function b(ctr) {
    var b = ctr;
}
```